# How to assign a value to a declared std::chrono::duration which has no value?

Tags: c++, duration, c++-chrono

How to do the equivalent of:

```
int n;
n = 1;
```

With `std::chrono::duration`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend using a raw `duration` type. Instead use a specific duration, like `seconds`, `nanoseconds`, etc.

```
std::chrono::nanoseconds ns;
ns = std::chrono::nanoseconds { 10 };
```

Although, if you insist, you can use your own specialized `duration` type:

```
std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 1>> diff;
diff = std::chrono::seconds { 3 };
-- OR --
diff = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 1>> { 3 };
```

I recommend:

- Using `nanoseconds` whenever you are not sure what resolution you need since it can contain any other standard `chrono::duration` value and it is a standard type
- Minimize uninitialized values in your program